# Analyzing site for MediaRequestProtection errors

Tags: media-library

We have a Sitecore site that was built on an older version of Sitecore and after upgrading to 8.1 we are experiencing a few thousand of MediaRequestProtection errors each day. After the upgrade, we did our best to find all of the places in code where custom media link building/rendering was performed to ensure that the hash was added, but unfortunately some slipped through the cracks. This is a very media-intensive site and I want to make sure that we get this issue corrected promptly.

The following is an example of the error:

```
1728 00:17:09 ERROR Resources.Media.MediaRequest MediaRequestProtection: An invalid/missing hash value was encountered. The expected hash value: F2E4CF4256335155E96722521B87026038DC32EC. Media URL: /-/media/sites/mysite/path/to/myimage.png?w=300&hash=F2E4CF4256335155E96722521B87026038DC32EC?w=60, Referring URL: https://mysite.com/some-page
```

I know that at the end of the URL, the `Referring URL` indicates the URL from which the media was requested, but we find new referring url's all the time and the client would like this issue resolved. Does anyone know if there is a tool or a script that can be used to help us identify on the site where these issues are occurring, or do we just have to take this one occurrence of the issue at a time?

Comment: You need to make sure first that all the code requesting the Media Url is hashed. Moreover, you may disable the config file to stop this issue. But I am pretty sure there are somewhere in the code that is still making use of the `GetMediaUrl` without passing it to the Hashed method. Even if the referring links changes most of the time, try to see what is common between them. It may be an editorial page or landing page.

Comment: @HishaamNamooya, I know how to fix the error. What I'm asking for is a way to crawl the site and identify anywhere that media URL hashing was missed or is invalid.